# java String pool entry and Heap entry mechanism

Tags: java, string

String s1 = new String("string") creates two object in java.one in String pool and one in heap. now if i write another statement after this like String s2 = "string". will it create another object in String pool or returns the previous object's reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String s2 = "string";` will return object from string pool.

```
    String s1 = new String("s");
    String s2 = "s"; // from pool
    String s3 = "s"; // from pool
    System.out.println(s1 == s2); // false
    System.out.println(s3 == s2); // true
```

Comment: that object which was created by calling new String("string") ?

Comment: "string" - is first object which would be put into string pool, new String("string") - is second object (not from string pool). s2 will be assigned to object from string pool.